# After Update Test Class Is Not Committing Change

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

I'm working on a test class for an after update trigger and I am running into an issue where the change that is being done is not being comitted by the DML operation. For example, if I look at the log and the system debug of the prior value and the current value there is no difference. However, if I perform a test in the UI the code behaves as expected. The test code in question is:

```java
public static testMethod void everythingisterrible() {

    Account newAccount = new Account();
    newAccount.name = 'Test';
    insert newAccount; 

    Project__c newProject = new Project__c();
    newProject.Shoot_Location_State_1__c = 'Arizona';
    newProject.Pre_Prep_Start_Date__c = date.newInstance(2020, 12, 3);
    newProject.Photography_Start_Date__c = date.newInstance(2020, 12, 15);
    newProject.Production_Company__c = newAccount.id; 
    newProject.Production_Title__c = 'Test';
    insert newProject; 

    newProject.Shoot_Location_State_1__c = 'California';
    update newProject; 
}
```

The related class is:

```java
public static void hatred(List<Project__c> projectList,Map<Id,Project__c> oldProjectMap) {
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for(project__c projId : projectList) {
            Project__c oldProject = oldProjectMap.get(projId.Id);
            system.debug('New' + projId.Shoot_Location_State_1__c);
            system.debug('Old' + oldProject.Shoot_Location_State_1__c);

        }
    }
}
```

And as for what I am seeing in the log when the class runs is as as follows:

[image: debug log]

Comment: How are you determining that the change isn't being committed (how are you checking the prior and current values)? Based on your description, it may just be that you need to _execute a query in your test method_ to grab the updated data. It'd also help if you shared more of your test method with us. You can [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: @DerekF just updated to include a screenshot of debug log, the class and the full test class. As shown in the system debug the value for New is not California as it should be per the test class

Comment: What's the code in the trigger that calls this method? You might just be accidentally passing the wrong trigger context variable.

Comment: Hi @DavidReed this is the code in the trigger:if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) ){
            
            ProjectTriggerHandler.hatred(trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);

        }

Comment: OK, new theory. Do you have more than one trigger, or any declarative automation (WFR, Process, Flow) on this object?

Comment: hi @DavidReed there are other classes being called on the trigger, and some declarative automation. But if those were affecting it wouldn't I see the issue when testing in the UI as well? Not just when trying to write the test class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your statement that

> there are other classes being called on the trigger, and some declarative automation

I am fairly confident that what's going on here is an update taking place during the processing of the initial `insert` DML.

That is, something in your org's customization runs during the insert operation (but not in `before insert` context, or a before-save Flow) and performs a record update to a field *other than* `Shoot_Location_State_1__c` that causes your trigger to fire again in an `update` context. Your logs then show no change because the field wasn't changed by the DML operation that is currently executing.

You can verify this theory by looking further down in your debug logs. I would expect that you will find your `update` trigger firing a second time (provided you don't have anything nasty like a static Boolean recursion blocker in there) and yielding the logs that you expect to see.

Comment: Hi David - after looking into it some more it looks like there is a boolean recursion blocker preventing the update from occuring with the test class. One method runs as an update, and then a second one (the one I am trying to test) runs. Any advice on how to best deal with this?

Comment: I actually found this other person's request for help that finally helped me cross that final hurdle: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000947oIAA

Comment: I'd love to point you towards [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-recursion-blocking-in-generic-trigger-handlers) in our canonical-QA section. It helps illuminate why the static Boolean pattern causes a lot of different harms, and offers some alternatives.