# can queueable method set a trigger handler static variable

Tags: apex, trigger, queueable-apex

Title of the question is mis-leading. Since yes, a queueable method can access a static variable of a class. But i have an existing old implementation, and i am trying to refactor and clean it up. There is a line in code that i dont think makes any difference, but wanted to get other people's opinion, since my experience level is limited

I have a trigger on case-

```
trigger caseTrigger on Case (before insert,before update, after insert, after update){
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
            if (Trigger.isInsert)  {/*do something*/} 
            if (Trigger.isUpdate) {/*do something*/}           }
        }

        if(Trigger.isAfter && !CaseTriggerHandler.afterCallsExecuted){
            if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                CaseTriggerHandler.afterUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.old);
            }
            if (trigger.isInsert) {
                CaseTriggerHandler.afterInsert(trigger.new);
            }
            CaseTriggerHandler.afterCallsExecuted = true; 
        }
}
```

From what i gather, the boolean variable CaseTriggerHandler.afterCallsExecuted is used to make sure afterInsert does not get execute more than once in case of recursion. All good here. My concern is in handler there is a place where they are setting it to true as well. And it's in a queueable method.

This is the code for trigger handler class (removed redundant stuff for sake of brevity)

```
public without sharing class CaseTriggerHandler{
    public static boolean afterCallsExecuted = false;

    public static void afterInsert(list<Case> newList) {
        CaseTriggerHandler.sendCaseToSalesforceOrg(newList, null);
    }

    public static void afterUpdate(list<Case> newList, list<Case> oldList) {
        CaseTriggerHandler.sendCaseToSalesforceOrg(newList, oldList);
    }

    private static void sendCaseToSalesforceOrg(list<Case> newList, list<Case> oldList){
        List<Id> caseIdsToSend = new List<Id>();
        //bunch of stuff to basically populate this List<Id> from newList
        //lets assume after this List<Id> has some list of IDs
        ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new JitterbitCalloutQueuebleJob(caseIds));
    }

    public class JitterbitCalloutQueuebleJob implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
        public List<Id> caseIds{get; set;}
        public JitterbitCalloutQueuebleJob(List<Id> caseIds){
          this.caseIds = caseIds;
        }
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
          CaseTriggerHandler.afterCallsExecuted = true; //does this here makes any sense?
          CaseTriggerHandler.jitterbitApiCallUtil(caseIds);
        }
    }

    public static String jitterbitApiCallUtil(List<Id> caseIds){
        //do all the work of transferring cases 
    }
}
```

So both after insert and after update call a method to transfer cases using jitterbit. This code is skeleton version of that, so i could show series of method calls.

JitterbitCalloutQueuebleJob.execute method sets that boolean variable to true.

From what i understand, this job will be queued, and case trigger is done. Later when the queued job is executed by server, sure it can set that handler class's boolean variable to true, but its pointless. Case trigger isn't even running right now. So goal to prevent recursion for after trigger isn't being addressed by this queueable job.

Just want o get other people's opinion on it. Want to make sure i am correct before i go about deleting that line.

Comment: Does `jitterbitApiCallUtil()` end up updating any `Case` records in Salesforce after the callout returns? If so, that'd be why the `execute()` method is setting that static var (otherwise you'd get into an endless callout loop).

Comment: @DerekF Oh my lanta ..... you are correct. Its updating cases. In those 2000 lines of code i missed that. Thank you so much. This answers it. If you post it as an answer, i could mark it as correct answer

Comment: Just an FYI: the use of a simple static Boolean to avoid recursion is certainly not "all good". Take a look at [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-recursion-blocking-in-generic-trigger-handlers/296748#296748).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say for certain without seeing all of the `jitterbitApiCallUtil()` method, but based on the comments, it does appear that this method is updating `Case` records after the callout is completed.

While `Queueable` preserves the object state of non-primitive typed member variables of the instance passed to `System.enqueueJob()`, the `execute()` method is still running in a new transaction. Static variables are reset, and that includes `CaseTriggerHandler.afterCallsExecuted`.

Re-setting that static variable in the `execute()` method prevents any updates to Cases from making another round of callouts.

Without that static variable being set, an update to any of the Cases whose Ids are passed into the `JitterbitCalloutQueuebleJob` constructor would cause you to set up an infinite chain of queuables + callouts.