# Possible Trigger and Process builder recursion

Tags: trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow, custom-object, recursion

I have created a Trigger on Order object. There is a field called pacing in both Order and Order product Objects. When the Pacing is updated in the Order, I am updating the Pacing field in the Order Products too that are related to that particular Order, using the below code.

```
if(ord.Pacing__c != oldOrd.Pacing__c) {
      changedPacing.put(ord.Id, ord);
      pacingMapVal.put(ord.Id, oldOrd.Pacing__c);
}

if(changedPacing.size() > 0) {
      OrderToOrderProductAutomation.updateLineItemRecord(changedPacing, null, null, null, pacingMapVal);
}

if(pacingArgMapVal != null && pacingArgMapVal.size() > 0) {
       List<OrderItem> updates = new List<OrderItem>();
       for (OrderItem detail : [SELECT Id, OrderId, Customer_Success_Manager__c, Line_Item_Start_Date__c, Line_Item_End_Date__c, Pacing__c
                                            FROM OrderItem
                                            WHERE OrderId IN :ordersListMap.keySet()]) {
            Order oso = ordersListMap.get(detail.OrderId);
            String pacing = oso.Pacing__c;
            if (detail.Pacing__c == pacingArgMapVal.get(detail.OrderId)) {
                 detail.Pacing__c = pacing;
                 updates.add(detail);
            }
        }
        update updates;
  }
```

I have created Process builder which creates a record in a custom Object called History__c whenever the a particular 6 fields are updated in Order, including the Pacing, by calling a flow using process builder.

Now whenever I am updating the pacing. 3 identical records are getting created in History Object. When I comment my trigger code, one History record is getting created as expected. Can anyone please let me know why this is happening and How can I sort this out.

Note: There are 3 roll-up summary fields in Order Object, to the Order Product object.

Comment: Take a look at the [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) where you'll see (step 14) that PBs and flows actually cause the entire "save" process to be re-executed if they update field values (perform DML). It is probably related to this. You can consider [blocking re-entrancy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-recursion-blocking-in-generic-trigger-handlers/296748#296748) though this may mean your custom objects hold the wrong data.

Comment: An alternative is to move the PB/flow handling into trigger code so it can be executed within the same scope and won't re-execute the save process.

Comment: @PhilW Thank you for you reply. Is it possible to get the Process builder ID in the trigger, and control the execution of the trigger by checking that ID?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.