# Only run trigger on first call pattern: Best practices

Tags: apex, trigger

Our previous Salesforce developer used the below 'first-call pattern' in **every** Apex trigger.

```
trigger ContactTgr on Contact (before insert) {
    public Static Boolean firstcall = True;
    //Test to see if this is the first call to this trigger
    if (!firstcall) {
        return;
    }   
    // actual trigger code..
    
    firstcall = false;
}
```

I wonder if this still applies. Is this pattern outdated, should it be used for certain types of triggers, or is actually a good idea?

Comment: cf. this excellent [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-recursion-blocking-in-generic-trigger-handlers/296817#296817). This particular static-Boolean pattern is poison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide you need recursion prevention, this approach is still the wrong way to go. When you use a `Boolean` to track first vs. subsequent entry, you will always prevent bulkification beyond 200 records. Use of `Set<Id>`, one per event, would be a much better pattern. However, in general, it is better to use proper filtering (especially making sure the relevant fields changed) before executing actions against trigger context records.

Comment: Thanks! I had a hunch that this was pattern was just a band-aid and now it turns out it is actually bad for bulkification. I think I have to review the record updates more closely and better remove this pattern altogether.