# Lightning: Edit recurring event series causes trigger to fire twice

Tags: trigger, lightning, after-trigger, lightning-events, recurring

In trying to create a trigger for recurring events, I'm noticing the trigger firing twice.

I'm doing this on a new and clean developer org, so no existing workflows, processes, flows, or triggers.

Also, only happens with Lightning (not Classic).

I've also gone down the path of using a static variable for testing if it gets set in the same run.

Here is my code:

TestLightningEventTrigger

```
trigger TestLightningEventTrigger on Event (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) { 
     if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        if (Trigger.isAfter) {
            if (TestLightningEventTriggerHandler.firstRun) {
                System.debug('>>>' + TestLightningEventTriggerHandler.firstRun);
                TestLightningEventTriggerHandler.firstRun = false;
                System.debug('>>>' + TestLightningEventTriggerHandler.firstRun);                                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TestLightningEventTriggerHandler

```
public class TestLightningEventTriggerHandler {
    public static Boolean firstRun = true;
}
```

Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Comment: how many events in the series you're editing?

Comment: I've tested with 5 and 10 events in the recurring series.

Comment: I'd be very wary about using a static Boolean in this way; you are limiting your org from handling bulk updates to events. Take a look at [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/296748/50252) for more about working around this (I realize this case isn't recursion, but a similar approach could be taken). As to why this is happening, I look forward to seeing an answer!

Comment: You're just updating one event in the series in the UI, correct? Doing a quick test on my end, it runs in 2 different transactions (my initial event edit and then salesforce updating all the other events in the series). Is that what you're referring to or are you seeing a different behavior?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves In the UI, I'm clicking the "Edit Series" button after save from editing an event.

Correct, when I print the Trigger.new, the first trigger event shows the single event and the 2nd trigger event shows all the events in the series.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have documentation that outright says this, but clicking on "edit series" in the UI seems to have the following occur:

[image]

1. First transaction with the single event you were on in the UI
2. Second transaction where that single event + all the other events in the series are updated

You can see this by doing the following on the event trigger

```
trigger testing on Event (after update) {
    for(Event evt : trigger.new){
        System.debug(evt.Id);
    }
}
```

You'll see two logs created for every event series edit. One with just one record (the record you edited in the UI to bring up the `edit series` modal) and then the other log with all the events in the series (*including the event from the first transaction*). That 2nd transaction is handled out-of-the-box.

This might explain the following limitation ([apex event trigger cannot handle batch operations on recurring events](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333582&type=1&mode=1)) since this could easily balloon if they allowed multiple event series in the same transaction.

Probably useful to point out another limitation also exists where there is [no series Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) for you to identify they all belong to the same series if you're looking to do some sort of exclusion logic to this behavior

> Lightning Experience event series have no series ID, so it’s not
> possible to locate other occurrences in the series. In Salesforce
> Classic recurring events, you can use RecurrenceActivityId to locate
> other occurrences.