# Run Trigger handler class in execute anonymous with old map newmap

Tags: apex, trigger, anonymous

**Trigger**

```
createCbQuoteTriggerHandler.getOpps(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
```

**Handler class**

```
public static void CreateOpportunity(Map<Id,Opportunity> oldData, List<Opportunity> newData){
        if(RecurringBoolean.StopRecurrsion)
        {
            Set<id> OppIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
            for(Opportunity n : newData){
                if ( n.StageName == 'Closed Won' && 
                    (oldData.isEmpty() || ( !oldData.isEmpty() && oldData.get(n.Id).StageName != n.StageName ))
                   ){
                    OppIdsSet.add(n.Id);   
                }
                
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, just provide the two parameters:

```
Opportunity[] newList = [SELECT StageName FROM Opportunity LIMIT 200];
Opportunity[] oldMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(newList.deepClone(true, true, true));
// Fix this to match the class name
TriggerHandlerClass.CreateOpportunity(newList, oldMap);
```

You can also just call it indirectly with some DML:

```
Opportunity[] newList = [SELECT StageName FROM Opportunity LIMIT 200];
update newList;
```

You can also change the values in the lists before calling the method if you're trying to test your logic.

Also, as a side note, your `RecurringBoolean.StopRecurrsion` check is invalid. You should read [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/296817/2984) on ideas for a better design, and why your current design should not be used.