# Strange ENTITY_IS_DELETED Error from this Method

Tags: apex, trigger, delete

Strange one...I'm getting ENTITY_IS_DELETED on the line below, but this method is the only thing that deletes these Account_Rule_Association__c records anywhere, and it is set in most cases to only run once, and even if it ran twice, it is querying the records itself before deleting, so it wouldn't find the records in the first place if they were deleted. It's a bit involved but if you care for some digging I'm all ears.

List<Database.DeleteResult> DeleteResults = Database.delete(ARAsToDelete, false);

Trigger context:

```
public void onAfterInsert(List<Account> Accs) { 
        FilterForAccountRules(Accs, new Map<Id, Account>());        
    }
    
    public void onBeforeUpdate(List<Account> Accs, Map<ID, Account> IDToOldAcc) {         
        FilterForAccountRules(Accs, IDToOldAcc);
    }
```

Method:

```
public void FilterForAccountRules(List<Account> Accs, Map<Id, Account> IdToOldAccount){    
        
        if (CheckRecursive.hasRun('FilterForAccountRules') || system.isBatch() ){return;}        
        CheckRecursive.markRun('FilterForAccountRules');    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>> In AccountHandler.FilterForAccountRules'); 
        
        Account [] AcctsToEvaluate = new List<Account>();
        Schema.FieldSetMember [] CriteriaFields = Schema.SObjectType.Account_Rule__c.fieldSets.getMap().get('Criteria').getFields();
      
        //if update, check if any fields were changed on the Account that would apply to an account rule
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            for (Account Acc : Accs){
                
                Account OldAcc = IdToOldAccount.get(Acc.Id);
                
                if(Acc.Territory2__c != OldAcc.Territory2__c){
                    AcctsToEvaluate.add(Acc);   system.debug('Territory2__c was changed from '+OldAcc.Territory2__c+' to '+Acc.Territory2__c); 
                    break;
                }
                for (Schema.FieldSetMember CriteriaField : CriteriaFields ) {   //system.debug('CriteriaField.getLabel() = '+CriteriaField.getLabel() );
                    if(CriteriaField.getLabel() == 'RecordType.Name'){                    
                        if(Acc.RecordTypeId != OldAcc.RecordTypeId){
                            AcctsToEvaluate.add(Acc);   system.debug(CriteriaField.getLabel()+ ' was changed' );
                            break;
                        }
                    }                                                                                                                                                
                    else if(Acc.get(CriteriaField.getLabel())  !=  OldAcc.get(CriteriaField.getLabel() ) ){
                        AcctsToEvaluate.add(Acc);   system.debug(CriteriaField.getLabel()+ ' was changed from '+OldAcc.get(CriteriaField.getLabel())+' to '+Acc.get(CriteriaField.getLabel() ) );
                        break;
                    }
                }    
            }
        }         
        else if(Trigger.isInsert){ 
            AcctsToEvaluate = Accs;
        }
        
        if(!AcctsToEvaluate.isEmpty() ){    system.debug('AccountHandler.FilterForAccountRules - About to send '+AcctsToEvaluate.size()+' accounts to RunAccountRules'); 
            RunAccountRules(AcctsToEvaluate, null);    
        }
    }    


public static void RunAccountRules(List<Account> Accs, ID OneTimeRuleID){     
                                                           
        if (CheckRecursive.hasRun('RunAccountRules')){return;}        
        CheckRecursive.markRun('RunAccountRules');    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>> In AccountHandler.RunAccountRules');
        
        //get existing Account_Rule_Associations, query all account rules, prioritize rules based on their criteria fields, then compare them to accounts, and update any matching accounts with field values based on priority
        Schema.FieldSetMember [] CriteriaFields = Schema.SObjectType.Account_Rule__c.fieldSets.getMap().get('Criteria').getFields();
        Schema.FieldSetMember [] AssignmentFields = Schema.SObjectType.Account_Rule__c.fieldSets.getMap().get('Assignments').getFields();   
            
        //get map of existing Account_Rule_Associations to potentially delete if account no longer matches them
        Map<ID, Account_Rule_Association__c[]> AccIDtoPreARAs = new Map<ID, Account_Rule_Association__c[]>();
        Map<ID, ID[]> AccIDtoPreRuleIDs = new Map<ID, String[]>();
        Map<ID, ID[]> AccIDtoPostRuleIDs = new Map<ID, String[]>();
        
        Account_Rule_Association__c [] ARAsToCreate = new List<Account_Rule_Association__c>();
        Account_Rule_Association__c [] ARAsToDelete = new List<Account_Rule_Association__c>();
        Account [] AccountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        
        for (Account_Rule_Association__c ARA: [SELECT ID, Account__c, Account_Rule__c FROM Account_Rule_Association__c WHERE Account__c IN :new Map<ID, Account>(Accs).keyset() FOR UPDATE]){
            if(!AccIDtoPreRuleIDs.keyset().contains(ARA.Account__c)){
                AccIDtoPreARAs.put(ARA.Account__c, new List<Account_Rule_Association__c>{ARA});
                AccIDtoPreRuleIDs.put(ARA.Account__c, new List<ID>{ARA.Account_Rule__c}); }
            else{
                AccIDtoPreARAs.get(ARA.Account__c).add(ARA);
                AccIDtoPreRuleIDs.get(ARA.Account__c).add(ARA.Account_Rule__c); }
        }
        
        Map<String, Account_Rule_Field_Priority__c> ARPs = Account_Rule_Field_Priority__c.getAll();
        
        String [] FieldNames = new List<String>(((SObject)Type.forName('Schema','Account_Rule__c').newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keyset());
        Account_Rule__c [] AccRules = Database.query('SELECT '+String.join(FieldNames, ',')+' FROM Account_Rule__c WHERE Rule_Type__c = \'Standing\' OR ID = :OneTimeRuleID');

        for (Account Acc : Accs){   system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> For Account: '+Acc.Name);
            
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> FieldToPriorityToValue = new Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>();
            Boolean AccHasMatchingRule = false;
                                 
            for (Account_Rule__c AR: AccRules){     system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> For Account Rule: '+AR.Name);
                                           
                Boolean MatchesThisRule = true;
                Integer Priority = 0;
                
                // determine if this rule matches this account, and also determine rule priority from criteria fields
                for (Schema.FieldSetMember CriteriaField : CriteriaFields) {    //system.debug('For CriteriaField '+CriteriaField.getLabel());
                                                                           
                    String CritLabel = CriteriaField.getLabel();                     
                    String CritValue = (String)AR.get(CriteriaField.getSObjectField() );                                        
                   
                    if(CritValue == null) continue; 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                    else{
                        String AccValue = CritLabel == 'RecordType.Name' ? CommonUtils.getRecordTypeNameById('Account', Acc.RecordTypeId) : String.valueOf(Acc.get(CritLabel));                            
                            system.debug('CritLabel = '+CritLabel);    system.debug('CritValue = '+CritValue);    system.debug('AccValue = '+AccValue);
                                                                          
                        //if Acc Rule field has a value, but Acc field value does not match it, then mark this as a non-match and continue to the next rule                        
                        if(AccValue == null || !CritValue.contains(AccValue) ){   
                            MatchesThisRule = false;    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>Rule Does Not Match! Proceeding to next one...');
                            break;    
                        }      
                        
                        //if this field has a priority value in the custom setting, and that priority is higher than any field evaluated so far, assign that priority number                        
                        else if(ARPs.get(CritLabel) != null && ARPs.get(CritLabel).Priority__c > Priority){
                            Priority = (Integer)ARPs.get(CritLabel).Priority__c;    //system.debug('Priority = '+Priority);
                        }
                    }
                }                          
                
                if(MatchesThisRule == false){continue;}
                                                                                               
                else{   system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>The rule '+AR.Name+', matched the account, yay');              
                    
                    AccHasMatchingRule = true; 
                     
                    //for each assignment field, add assignment value to the map for later assignment to the account, checking against priority values of previously matching rules                         
                    for(Schema.FieldSetMember AssignField : AssignmentFields){
                                                                              
                        String AssignLabel = AssignField.getLabel();          
                        String AssignValue = (String)AR.get(AssignField.getSObjectField() );    
                                                                                
                        if(AssignValue == null) continue;
                                             
                        else if(!FieldToPriorityToValue.keySet().contains(AssignLabel)){     //if not in map already, add field along with current rule priority and field value                                        
                            FieldToPriorityToValue.put(AssignLabel, new Map<Integer, String>{Priority => AssignValue} );      
                        }
                        else if(Priority > new List<Integer>(FieldToPriorityToValue.get(AssignLabel).keyset())[0] ){  //if it is in map, and this rule has higher priority than previous ones, replace the priority/value                                 
                            FieldToPriorityToValue.put(AssignLabel, new Map<Integer, String>{Priority => AssignValue} );
                        }                                                                            
                    }
                    
                    // add this matching rule to the post map, to later be compared to the pre map, to determine if any previous matching rule associations need to be deleted 
                    if(!AccIDtoPostRuleIDs.keyset().contains(Acc.ID)){                          
                        AccIDtoPostRuleIDs.put(Acc.ID, new List<ID>{AR.Id}); 
                    }
                    else{
                        AccIDtoPostRuleIDs.get(Acc.ID).add(AR.Id); 
                    } 
                    
                    //if this Account currently has no rules, or this matching rule is not already associated with this account, create a new Account_Rule_Association__c record to insert
                    if(AccIDtoPreRuleIDs.get(Acc.ID) == null || !AccIDtoPreRuleIDs.get(Acc.ID).contains(AR.ID)){         
                        ARAsToCreate.add(new Account_Rule_Association__c(Account__c = Acc.ID, Account_Rule__c = AR.ID));     
                    }
                }                    
            }//end of rule loop 
       
                //system.debug('Map of fields from one or more rules being applied to this Account = '+json.serializePretty(FieldToPriorityToValue));
            
            // make all actual field assignments here, based on priorities assigned to each field above
            if(AccHasMatchingRule == true){                                               
                if(Trigger.IsExecuting && Trigger.isUpdate){
                    for(String AssignLabel : FieldToPriorityToValue.keyset()){                     
                        Acc.put(AssignLabel, FieldToPriorityToValue.get(AssignLabel).values()[0]);                   
                    }
                        //system.debug('AccountHandler.RunAccountRules - Successfully updated this Account in before update context');
                }
                else if(system.isBatch() || (Trigger.IsExecuting && Trigger.isInsert) ){
                    Account AccToUpdate = new Account(ID = Acc.ID); 
                    for(String AssignLabel : FieldToPriorityToValue.keyset()){                    
                        AccToUpdate.put(AssignLabel, FieldToPriorityToValue.get(AssignLabel).values()[0]);
                    }
                    AccountsToUpdate.add(AccToUpdate);
                } 
            }
            else{
                system.debug('AccountHandler.RunAccountRules - No matching rules for this account :(');
            }
        }   //end of account loop
        
                
        for(ID AccID : AccIDtoPreARAs.keyset()){    //for each account
            for(Account_Rule_Association__c ARA : AccIDtoPreARAs.get(AccID)){   // for each ARA previously assigned to that account
                if(AccIDtoPostRuleIDs.get(AccID) == null  ||   //if there are no matching rules after this update OR
                   !AccIDtoPostRuleIDs.get(AccID).contains(ARA.Account_Rule__c)){   //the list of currently matching rules does not contain this previously matching rule
                        ARAsToDelete.add(ARA);    
                }
            }
        }            
        
        if(!AccountsToUpdate.isEmpty()){    system.debug('AccountHandler.RunAccountRules - About to update '+AccountsToUpdate.size()+' accounts');
            try{    
                update AccountsToUpdate;
                    system.debug('AccountHandler.RunAccountRules - updated '+AccountsToUpdate.size()+' newly inserted or batch-called Account records with Account Rule assignments');
                        if(Test.isRunningTest()) {integer intTest = 1/0;}
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                SystemLogUtil.ExceptionLog('AccountHandler.RunAccountRules', e , 'Exception occurred trying to update newly inserted or batch-called Account records with Account Rule assignments');
                    system.debug('AccountHandler.RunAccountRules - Failed to update newly inserted or batch-called Account records with Account Rule assignments - error message: '+e);                     
            }
        }  
        
        if(!ARAsToCreate.isempty()  ||  !ARAsToDelete.isempty() ) {     system.debug('AccountHandler.RunAccountRules - Preparing to call queueable CreateDeleteARAs...');                       
            CreateDeleteARAs Job = new CreateDeleteARAs();
                Job.ARAsToCreate = ARAsToCreate;     
                Job.ARAsToDelete = ARAsToDelete;                                                      
                    system.enqueueJob(Job);           
        }  
        
        system.debug('DML Rows = '+Limits.getDmlRows());    system.debug('DML Rows Limit ='+Limits.getLimitDmlRows());
        system.debug('Query Rows ='+Limits.getQueryRows());    system.debug('Query Rows Limit ='+Limits.getLimitQueryRows());
        system.debug('CPU Time = '+Limits.getCpuTime());    system.debug('CPU Time Limit ='+Limits.getLimitCpuTime());
        system.debug('Heap = '+Limits.getHeapSize());    system.debug('Heap Limit ='+Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
    }
```

Called queueable:

```
public class CreateDeleteARAs implements Queueable{        
        
        public Account_Rule_Association__c [] ARAsToCreate = new List<Account_Rule_Association__c>();
        public Account_Rule_Association__c [] ARAsToDelete = new List<Account_Rule_Association__c>();
        
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        
            if(!ARAsToDelete.isEmpty()){    system.debug('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs - About to delete '+ARAsToDelete.size()+' ARAs');
                try{
                    List<Database.DeleteResult> DeleteResults = Database.delete(ARAsToDelete, false);
                
                    for(Database.DeleteResult Result : DeleteResults){                                                                 
                        if(!Result.isSuccess()){ 
                            SystemLogUtil.GenericLog('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs', 'Failed to delete ARA with ID '+Result.getid()+': Errors - ', Result.getErrors()[0] ); 
                                system.debug('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs - Failed to delete Account_Rule_Association__c record - error message: '+Result.getErrors());
                        }                    
                    }    
                    system.debug('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs - Deleted '+ARAsToDelete.size()+' old Account_Rule_Association__c records, errors above if any');
                        if(Test.isRunningTest()) {integer intTest = 1/0;}
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    SystemLogUtil.ExceptionLog('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs', e , 'Exception occurred trying to delete Account_Rule_Association__c records');
                        system.debug('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs - Failed to delete Account_Rule_Association__c records - error message: '+e);
                }
            }
            
            if(!ARAsToCreate.isEmpty()){    system.debug('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs - About to create '+ARAsToCreate.size()+' ARAs');
                try{
                    List<Database.SaveResult> SRs = Database.insert(ARAsToCreate, false);
                
                    for(Database.SaveResult SR : SRs){                                                                 
                        if(!SR.isSuccess()){ 
                            SystemLogUtil.GenericLog('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs', 'Failed to insert ARA with ID '+SR.getid()+': Errors - ', SR.getErrors()[0] ); 
                                system.debug('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs - Failed to insert Account_Rule_Association__c record - error message: '+SR.getErrors());
                        }                    
                    }    
                    system.debug('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs - inserted '+ARAsToDelete.size()+' Account_Rule_Association__c records, errors above if any');
                        if(Test.isRunningTest()) {integer intTest = 1/0;}
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    SystemLogUtil.ExceptionLog('CreateDeleteARAs', e , 'Exception occurred trying to insert new Account_Rule_Association__c records');
                        system.debug('AccountHandler.CreateDeleteARAs - Failed to insert new Account_Rule_Association__c records - error message: '+e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to add what causes this method to be invoked (e.g. a trigger on Account?) and verify that you do not have any automation that could cause the side effects you are seeing? BTW a simple boolean check for recursion avoidance is an anti-pattern. See this [Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-recursion-blocking-in-generic-trigger-handlers) if you are in trigger context.

Comment: Sure, added. I know the simple recursion prevention is an anti-pattern but isn't an issue in this case. If anything, it would only prevent this particular issue even more. I can confirm no other code or declarative operates on Account_Rule_Association__c records.