# Is solving trigger recursion using Map<TriggerOperation, Set<Id>> Scalable in terms of heap size?

Tags: apex, trigger

There are many ways of solving apex trigger recursion using Static Boolean flags, static set of ids, static map of operation to set of Ids.

The old official documentation from Salesforce.com to fix recursion using static Boolean flag is not right as it works only for total records of 200. If the total records were 300 it would fail as static boolean flag is spread across all the batches/all records.

Of all, I feel that static Map<TriggerOperation, Set> blockedObjectIdsByOperation from [What is a good pattern for recursion blocking in generic trigger handlers?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296745/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-recursion-blocking-in-generic-trigger-handlers/296817#296817) is the right pattern.

Even though it makes sense with the above reference, Im really worried if I want to update 50 million records through data loader on an object. Since storing each processed Id would take up around 26 bytes in map. For 50 million records it would be more than 1 GB of heap space. I m not sure If I am missing something. Please throw some light on this.

Comment: In addition to the above, I see some suggestion around emptying the Map<TriggerOperation, Set> for every 1000 records of bulk data load. It might sound interesting. But, Im not able to for-see any repercussions of using this approach.

Comment: so you wanted to not run same id an event more than once in the same transaction. if you apply the emptying once per every 1000 records, why cant you do for every 200 records. heap size for synchnous call is 6 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Data Loader transactions (and indeed, any API call) are limited to 200. When you load 50 million records, you're loading 250,000 calls of 200 records each. The limits reset between each transaction, as does the heap usage, so there's no concern there.

When possible, using a single flag is the more appropriate option. The trick, as I stated in my previous answer, is to set the flag before doing a potentially recursive operation, then resetting the flag afterwards. The reset step is important, because that allows partial retries to work correctly, as well as recursive updates that may occur from workflow rules, flows, etc.

My personal favorite is to simply check which records need to be updated (e.g. they differ in values), rather than blindly update all records and depend on a recursion blocking scheme. But if I absolutely need to block recursion, I'm going to use the set flag, do DML, reset flag pattern. It's the safest recursion blocker that will work 100% of the time if you are also already filtering for "only necessary updates."

Give it a try sometime, and see how efficient it can be to simply prefer *not* to update records, rather than to try and block recursion. It's much easier to avoid the infinite loop than to break the infinite loop with a flag.

Here's a trivial example. Let's say we want to update the account's description from the contact's description. We can do this efficiently with:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([
  SELECT Description FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :Trigger.new
]);
Map<Id, Account> oldValues = new Map<Id, Account>();
Map<Id, Account> newValues = new Map<Id, Account>();
for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
  oldValues.put(
    record.AccountId, 
    new Account(
      Id=record.AccountId,
      Description=accounts.get(record.AccountId).Description
    )
  );
  newValues.put(
    record.AccountId,
    new Account(
      Id=record.AccountId,
      Description=record.Description
    )
  );
}
for(Id accountId: newValues.keySet().clone()) {
  if(oldValues.get(accountId) == newValues.get(accountId)) {
    newValues.remove(accountId);
  }
}
update newValues.values();
```

While this example is overly complicated, it scales well with 10, 20, or even 100 fields. As many as you need. You could even write this out as a generic method with an interface or class that handles most of the work for you.

Note that there's no error handling and null checks, this is more illustrative than prescriptive, but hopefully you'll get the main point that it's easier to deal with recursion when you're not updating records that don't need to be updated, rather than blocking the triggers with any kind of static variable.

If you consider the trigger above for Contacts, and a similar one for Accounts (to update all Contact descriptions to match), you'll notice that the record that triggered the original update won't recurse back to the original contact, because the description will already match the new value. By checking for changes before applying them, you'll break almost all types of recursion naturally without any flags at all.

Comment: Wait a minute, isn't it the batch size (with a maximum value of 10,000) the determiner of the transaction boundry here?

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the Detailed explanation. If static variables(as they share values across transactions in trigger of multiple batches) memory does not increase over each processed transaction, then that should work.

Comment: @DerekF Batches are always in 200, though. Even the Bulk API's 10k batches are 200 each.

Comment: @pioneer static variables do not share across transactions, they are always initially clear of any values.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks @sfdcfox. Made my day :)

Comment: While I agree only process records that actually need processing, a simple static Boolean will not work in all scenarios. You may have trigger A cause trigger B cause trigger A for a different (though potentially intersecting) set of A records and your simple Boolean won't deal with this case right. Yes, we have had this sort of arrangement and needed something better than a static Boolean.

Comment: Also, the comments above around "batch size" are confusing. I think you mean maximum scope size (which is max 200 in SObject and 2000 in Platform Event).

Comment: @PhilW (a) I'm convinced there are not any scenarios that actually *require* recursion blocking of any type. I used to think that recursion blocking was inevitable, but I'm pretty sure more creativity is needed, and (b) all API calls are limited to 200 records (e.g. OP was suggesting updating 30,000,000 records and running out of heap).

Comment: @PhilW I mean, you could be right that there's a recursion that can only be solved with the static set idea, and I've used that historically, but all of those scenarios seemed to resolve themselves with more intelligent updates. I'd love to have an example that I can't solve with selective DML updates alone. If you have any you can legally share, my email's always open.

Comment: I will see if I can provide a stripped down scenario description. On the number of records, Apex and other automations can obviously impact up to 10000 records in a sync transaction, and this could itself be initiated through a custom REST API.

Comment: BTW, I agree that many, many cases do not need recursion blocking if done right.

Comment: @sfdcfox While I was going through your previous comments(static variables do not share across each transaction/scope/batch in triggers, they are always initially clear of any values.), something popped up in my mind about that.

 If using static Boolean flags shares its value(alreadyProcessed = 'true' for eg.,) set from first batch/transaction, then second batch/transaction would skip processing. If this is true, then how come Set of Ids not accumulate over multiple transactions/batches in the trigger of 20k(for eg) records dml operation.

Comment: @pioneer In a batch process, static variables are reset between each transaction. The flag isn't shared across transactions (and my apologies if anything I said seemed to imply that). Either technique can work, but the flag needs to be managed carefully, either by Boolean or by Set/Map. Records can be processed more than once for various reasons, such as partial DML updates and so on.

Comment: @sfdcfox  I am just trying to compare the widespread process/practices from Salesforce advocates regarding usage of static Boolean flags vs static set of Ids in Trigger Context. If boolean flag status is shared across transactions in multiple trigger batches(thats why most people recommend not to use it as dml operation on 200+  records wouldn't work on this approach), why not static set of Ids accumulate over multiple trigger batches.

Comment: @pioneer It doesn't matter if you use a flag or a Set of Ids; it matters that you reset the recursion blocker at the end of each trigger operation. The Set of Ids was a workaround that people came up with when they realized the Boolean flags were breaking things like unit tests, and never realized it was the fact that the recursion blocking solution itself wasn't complete. Repetition is not recursion, which is why neither solution is typically the answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox That makes sense that neither of that works without a reset. Surprisingly, this is not discussed in this detail any where. Thanks for the detail. 
   The above example that you posted does not show where you are resetting flags. Can you please post some example or thoughts as it seems tricky to find the end of each batch/scope and reset flags as sometimes second dml/update happens through workflow or some process kickoff.

Comment: @sfdcfox  Also, If I understand correctly, in your example and use case you have the luxury to compare whether a particular field is changed. Lets say, I have a use case of publishing platform event when certain criteria is matched in dml update, then we cannot compare old and new sobject records.

Comment: @pioneer In an ideal scenario, blocks should be placed around the potentially recursive logic, such as `blockRecursion(); doSomeDml(); unblockRecursion();` However, that can be cumbersome, especially with other possibly unknown automations, so a full trigger block may be waranted, but it should still look like `blockRecursion(); doTriggerLogic(); unblockRecursion();` ... we must allow the same records to be potentially updated more than once to make sure all business logic is enforced. Repetition is not (necessarily) recursion.

Comment: @pioneer And as far as the publishing upon criteria, I would state that the only meaningful publishes would be those that are due to changes. Anything more than that is wasteful. Even in the case of updating external systems, it's easy enough to check for valid changes to avoid infinite loops.